# how to embed base64 image format in raphael paper.image

Tags: javascript, ipad, raphael

i am converting image file into base64 in server side and writing that base64 into txt file in client side(ipad).
now i need to place that base encode format in raphael paper.image(src,height.width) to have an background image.
pl help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a live example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/acaloc/6/edit)